# Is there an ODBC Driver for MariaDB in IBM PASE?

Tags: mariadb, odbc, ibm-midrange

As part of the open-source software on PASE for i, MariaDB is available in the ibm repository. However, it seems like the [MariaDB Connector/ODBC](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-connector-odbc/) is not available.

Following the [Building MariaDB Connector/ODBC From the Git Repository](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/building-mariadb-connectorodbc-from-source/) instructions does not work, since it appears that PASE is not supported. Forking it and modifying the source + build toolchain to work in PASE seems like a potential (but unattractive) option.

Is there a MySQL ODBC driver that can be used instead? Have I missed an available package? I also noticed that Zend / Seiden / etc have discussed using PHP with MySQL / MariaDB on PASE for i, how is PHP connecting to MariaDB in that case?

Comment: the place to ask is ryver.  IBM i developers host a forum there. https://ibmioss.ryver.com/index.html#forums/1000126

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69726450/3245633

Since most languages have a way to connect to MySQL/MariaDB without the ODBC interface/libraries, why do you need an ODBC driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM does not currently provide an ODBC interface for connecting to MariaDB. Most high level languages provide a MySQL/MariaDB interface which does not require the client libraries (eg. PyMySQL).

Comment: Please clarify whether those "We" are the publishers. Also, please do not ask questions in answer, use your commenting privilege for that.